# white space and title not being displayed

Tags: html, css, django, twitter-bootstrap

There is a spacing of about 20 pixels separating my body and the top of the browser. I cant seem to create a remove this and create a 0 distance. Also my title isnt being displayed. I can't seem to figure out what is causing this.

css:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;

}
.background {
    background-color:#b0a0e6;
}

.wrapper {
    background-color: grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 75%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <!-- Base css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static "css/default.css" %}">

  </head>
  <body class="background">
    <div class="wrapper">   
      <h1>Hello, world!</h1>


    </div>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: try selecting the spacing up top with dev tools element selector with a webkit browser. in addition, throw in `padding:0px;margin:0px;`

Comment: @DylanMadisetti thank you for your response but that did not fix the issue =[

Comment: Selecting the spacing with the item selector should have revealed the spacing belonging to h2. Check out Normalize CSS for removing other default kinks http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The spacing is created by the default `margin` of the `h1`. To remove the spacing you can make the margin of `h1` to `0`

```
.wrapper h1{
   margin-top:0
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/MB3J2/1/)** with `margin-top:0`

OR

Give `overflow:auto` to `.wrapper` which will keep the margin of `h1` and remove the top spacing.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/MB3J2/)** with `overflow auto`